# Taking the limit of a defined function

Tags: functions, function-construction

The Fibonacci function I have constructed is:

`f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]`

`f[0] = 0; f[1] = 1;`

`\[ScriptF][n_] := \[ScriptF][n] = f[n] + f[n - 1]`

Is there a way to take the limit of the ratios of

`\[ScriptF][n_] := \[ScriptF][n] = f[n] + f[n - 1]` / `f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]`

as n tends to infinity?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) and[`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) will do the equivalent:

```
Clear[f];
rsol = RSolve[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}, f, n]
(*  {{f -> Function[{n}, Fibonacci[n]]}}  *)

Limit[f[n]/f[n - 1] /. First[rsol], n -> Infinity]
(*  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])  *)
```

Comment: An equivalent solution: `f = DifferenceRoot[Function[{f, n}, {f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[0] == 0, f[1] == 1}]]; Limit[f[n + 1]/f[n] // FunctionExpand, n -> ∞]`

Answer (score 3):

Or use the built in function Fibonnaci:

```
Limit[Fibonacci[n + 1]/Fibonacci[n], n -> Infinity]
(*  1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5])  *)
```